# renumbering a file based on another one in R

Tags: r

Using R, I would like to replace the content of one file based on another file. The example may make it easier to see what I want to do:

File1:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1  5    3   4
2  6    3   0
3  7    6   5
4  9    7   4
```

File2

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    5
[4,]    4    6
[5,]    5    7
[6,]    6    9
```

I would like to replace the numbers in file1 by their matches on column 1 from file2. For example, 5 in file1 would be replaced by 3 nad 7 by 5 etc. The output file would be:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
1  3    1   2
2  4    1   0
3  5    4   3
4  6    5   2
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on how your matching work?

Comment: Matching would be based on file2

Comment: I think the first value in the last row of your example output should be 6, not 9, based on the matching rule?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets you most of the way. It assumes you know in advance that `file1` has 3 columns - you could use `ncol = ncol(file1)` instead, if not.

```
file3 <- matrix(match(file1, file2[, 2]), ncol = 3)

file3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    1    2
[2,]    4    1   NA
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    2
```

NA is generated as there is no match for 0. You can replace it.

```
file3[is.na(file3)] <- 0
```

Comment: Maybe `m <- match(file1, file2[,2]); replace(file1, !is.na(m), na.omit(m))` if non-matches aren't to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option by creating a look-up vector and using `match`. `file3` is the final output.

```
look_up <- file2[, 2]
names(look_up) <- file2[, 1]

value <- match(file1, look_up)
value[is.na(value)] <- 0

file3 <- matrix(value, ncol = 3)
file3
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    1    2
# [2,]    4    1    0
# [3,]    5    4    3
# [4,]    6    5    2
```

**DATA**

```
file1 <- matrix(c(5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 0, 7, 6, 5, 9, 7, 4), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
file2 <- matrix(c(1:6, 3:7, 9), ncol = 2)
```

Comment: We had the same thought at the same time :)

Comment: @neilfws Your solution is more concise. Nice one.